# Call JavaScript only if validation is success in jsf 1.2 and richface 3.2

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2

I have a jsf action and JavaScript.

jsf action basically contain Server Side validation logic.

And with the JavaScript I am calling some third party services which use my form data.

**But before calling that JavaScript I just wanted to ensure that the entered value is correct and validated means no error messages in `facesMessages`.

 And if validation fails then user will be on the same page with the error message otherwise call the JavaScript.**

I have implemented `<a4j:commandButton>` and `<a4j:jsFunction>` but somehow it is not working consistently in case of validation fail. Sometime my error message not appear on UI and some time it does.

```
<a4j:commandButton id="BTN" value="BTN" image="img" onclick="callValidationFunction();/>

<a4j:jsFunction name="callValidationFunction" data="bean.valiateDataAction" oncomplete="callJavaScriptFunction();" />
```

Can anyone please help what is wrong with what I am doing or **is there any other way to do** this?

Comment: Any comments on this ...

Comment: You can do validation in action of commandButton and oncomplete call jsFunction with third party javascript.